# Ways to increase performance of an application

Tags: java, performance, database-performance

I work on a Production system which is built up using Java Environment, Oracle Database and a Weblogic application server supporting 50 users.

I would like to know how do I improve performance of this application on time, on the spot , if the number of users accessing this application grow at large and if I face performance issues.

I think the ways are to

1. Increase the Connection pooling capacity
2. Increase the cache size

We face the slowness in the application with following issues

1. Strucks threads inside Weblogic related to pending DB requests
2. Growing number of users accessing LDAP.

I was said that these fixes are for long time. I would like to know how do I come up with a solution such as to give a performance boost on time, on the spot when the issue is faced.

Comment: This is impossible to answer with the information you provided. Are specific queries slow? Are there concurrency/locking issues? Is there code that is slow in some situations? You should pinpoint the actual cause of the slowness rather than just adding resources and hope the performance will improve.

Comment: Yeah, I too think that there is not particular solution to fix the performance issue on time and there are no solutions which happen in short time. Code fixes or adding resources, load balancing all of them take time.

Comment: edited the Question

Comment: My first comment also applies to your edited question. What threads are blocked exactly? What do they do? Which specific call is slow? Pinpoint your performance issue(s) so you can analyse it (or ask questions about it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you give more specifics, I can only say yes and yes....sort of. I would recommend reading these two articles to get an idea of how you should prioritize scaling:

- [Scaling Your Java EE Applications - TheServerSide](https://web.archive.org/web/20160420185629/http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363681/Scaling-Your-Java-EE-Applications)
- [The Basics of Scaling Java EE Applications - DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/the-basics-of-scaling-java-ee-applications)

I personally find that state-less API's are most often inherently more scale-able and are something to strive for.

Comment: I too know the solution of Load balancing which also takes time. I think there is no solution to fix the performance issues on the spot.

Comment: If threads are getting stuck in DB requests you may be dealing with a deadlock somewhere. I recommend going over the queries (maybe the DB log if you have one set up) and see what the database traffic looks like. I don't have any LDAP experience but this may help you https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13707/ldap.htm#SECMG328